# Display multiple "save draft button" on a post edit

Tags: metabox, buttons, draft

I am aware of the `submit_button()` and `get_submit_button()` function, but can I call a "save draft" button on the same way? I have a very long "edit post page" and would like to display the save draft button various time

Comment: Drafts are automatically saved by default. No need to introduce a special button to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes they are, but I had to disable the automatic save because of the large amount of data on the post.

Answer (score 0):

One really simple way is to just insert another "save draft" button wherever you want in your post editor page.

`<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Draft" class="button">`

You essentially just want to make sure it's got "save" as it's `name` attribute and "Save Draft" as it's `value`.